# React-Native dropdown autocomplete alignment

Tags: css, react-native, autocomplete, alignment, dropdown

I am having difficulty aligning the dropdown to come just below the autompletebox. There seem to be another View below the input box pushing the dropdown away. I am using this library. https://github.com/maxkordiyak/react-native-dropdown-autocomplete and .

Somebody help me :)

Snapshot below is current dropdown and inputfield:

[image: snapshot of below current dropdown and inputfield]

Code snapshot

```
 <View>
      <Input 
        ref={this.input}
        inputContainerStyle={styles.assetIDfield}
        containerStyle={styles.IDfieldContainer}
        label=“Search by ID”
        labelStyle={styles.IDLabel}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        value={this.state.ID}
        onChangeText={this.onIDTextChange} 
        />
    </View>
  </View>

<View style={styles.assetIDUserNameContainer} >
      <View containerStyle={ styles.userFilterContainer}>

      <Text>Search by User Name/Text>
      <Autocomplete 
      inputStyle={styles.userFilterfield}
      data ={this.state.usernameData}
      valueExtractor={item => item }  
      // inputContainerStyle={styles.dropDownContainer}

      ref={this.userFilter}
      initialValue={firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}
      // overlayStyle={styles.dropDownContainer}
      onChangeText={this.onUsernameTextChange}
      separatorStyle={styles.separatorStyle}
      noDataTextStyle={styles.noDataTextStyle}
      scrollStyle={styles.scrollStyle}
      pickerStyle={styles.pickerStyle}
      listHeader="Results"
      noDataTextStyle="No data"
      // containerStyle={styles.dropDownContainer}
      // onDropdownShow={ () => onDropdownShow()}
      />
       {/* <ScrollView>

      <View containerStyle={ styles.dropDownContainer}/>
      </ScrollView> */}
 </View>
```

Comment: can you provide a piece of code, to check what's going wrong

Comment: how do you have created your drop-down?

Comment: @user12129132 I have added the code snippets